# Unable pass NSString into NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-text, nsattributedstring

I want to create a display that shows a heading, sub-headings, an embedded image, and regular text (somewhat similar to a wikipedia style page). I have my heading, sub-headings, image, and regular text all in strings.  I understand an AttributedString is the best way to achieve my desired formatting.  What I cannot figure out is how to create the AttributedString from my pre-existing strings.

```
displayText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:@"%@ \n %d - %@", self.currentInstance.name, self.currentInstance.number, self.currentInstance.image];
textView.attributedText = displayText;
```

I'm new so I'm sure it's something basic I am doing wrong.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: What errors are you getting? It looks like you are passing a normal string where it is expecting an attributed string.

Comment: You should be using initWithString: not initWithAttributedString: since what you're passing in are NSStrings.

Comment: The errors I'm getting are "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSAttributedString *'" and "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 4".

Comment: Use the proper selector: [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:<your string>] and then you can set the attributes in your mutable attributed string.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for answering. initWithString produces the same error as initWithAttributedString.  I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
displayText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
```

Then add your attributes (i may have spelling mistakes because I typed this in the comment box, but this should work.